# How to give a browser extension all text data input into that browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, event-listener, html-input

I'm experimenting with Chrome browser extensions. I want to be able to take any text input into the browser (through the URL bar of the browser or onto text boxes on social media sites and so on) and send that text to a server. I'm wondering if this is possible in chrome and what functions I need to use to achieve this?

I suspect the logic of the extension would work something like this: any time a link is clicked where there is text in an input form / text box, extract that text or form input and send it using some JS requests library to a server.

Which Chrome API function can be used to get the text input into a form?

Comment: There is no dedicated API. As you can see in the overview article in the  documentation, content scripts can access the web page DOM so you can use that to find the text elements. The address bar is off limits, it's not exposed, but in most cases you can intercept the input in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener that will be invoked for the default search engine URL with the user text in some parameter, q= by default for the Google search URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **DOM** information (*input*, *textareas*, etc) using **content_script** which has direct access to the web page data.  URL data can be accessed through either the **popup.js** or **background.js** using the chrome API [chrome.tab.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

In the past I have had the best luck using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), this looks at real-time changes to the web page (or wherever you specify you want the observer to be).  Then you can send that data to the server.

small example.

```
function extractinputdata() {
var inputdata = document.getElementById('some specfic HTML element')
  if (inputdata != null) {
    new MutationObserver(function(){
      //when a change has been made to the element or its children, you can record the new data
    }).observe(inputdata, {characterData: true, childList: false, subtree:true});
  }
}
```